# I am trying to get URL from string using JAVA

Tags: java, android, variables

I am trying to get URL from string using JAVA. but my variable not working in "Uri.parse" section (no value in variable). please consider i am beginner in coding

**Error is : " Cannot assign a value to final variable 'result' "**

My code:

```
showResultDialogue(result.getContents());
```

..

```
public void showResultDialogue(final String result) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }


        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\.]+\\.(?:com|cc|net|ru|in)[^,\\s]*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(result);


        builder.setTitle("Example Title")
                .setMessage("Text is " + result);


        if(m.matches()) {
            builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(result) // here is problem
                    );
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: what is the error stacktrace?

Comment: @SamzSakerz there is nothing in 'result' variable

Comment: Can you edit your question with the error log if there is any? and send me what you are inputting in result.

Comment: @SamzSakerz input is "globalist.in/somthing.html" . regex matching was success ful, but didn't open url in browser

Comment: I see, Can you try my suggestions and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have provided no information of why it does not work, I am just gonna assume the URL is missing `http` since you're regex does not match that, in that case I would just do this

Edit: do you really need your regex? Android has a built in way of matching URLS.

You can find the docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns

`Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result).matches();`

so your code is gonna look like this

```
if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result).matches()) {
    builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(!result.startsWith("http://") && !result.startsWith("https://") ? "http://" + result : result)
            );
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: input is "globalist.in/somthing.html" . regex matching was successful, but didn't open url in browser

Comment: didn't work. Error is : " Cannot assign a value to final variable 'result' "